# View Background HTML page in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension. The purpose is to display data gathered from several servers on a page. I am utilizing the Chrome extension's ability to run as a background process whenever the PC is on so that data is always being gathered.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "Data Hub",
   "description": "This extension gathers and analyzes data from several servers",
   "version": "1.0",

   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "background": {
      "page": "background.html"
   },
   "permissions":[
      "background"
   ],
}
```

**Popup.html** and **Popup.js**

Opens a new instance of Background.html when the popup icon is clicked.

**Work.js**

Infinite loop: makes AJAX requests, processes data, and updates Background.html. Script is located in my extension's folder.

**Background.html**

Each instance calls its own instance of Work.js.

---

If I click the popup, a new instance of Background.html opens in a new tab. I can see in the `chrome://extensions/` that there are now 2 instances of Background.html. It begins displaying data starting at this instant in time and I can see the page's HTML elements. When the tab is closed, that data is lost.

I would like to be able to see the HTML elements of the original Background.html page. The original instance has been running since start-up and continues running when Chrome is closed, and therefore it contains all the data.

In `chrome://extensions/` when I click to view the original instance of Background.html, I can only see the developer tools, not the HTML elements on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a file is named background.html it doesn't become a background page when you open it in a tab. It becomes just another page that has its own context, document, window - and it all exists only until that tab is closed. The extensions have just one real background page that's declared in `"background"` section of manifest.json.

Make sure to read the [extensions architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and rework your code. You can persist data in [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or you can use [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) in other pages of your extension to access the real and only background page `window` object that will expose global variables and functions.

Comment: I suppose I mean to ask is there a simple way to copy all of the HTML elements from my real background page to some new page that is visible to the user? My code works to display all the data on the real but invisible background page.

Comment: Elements can't be copied between different pages but you can copy their html.